# What are best use cases of shared_ptr, unique_ptr and weak_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, unique-ptr, weak-ptr

While it is easy to learn about `std::shared_ptr`, `std::unique_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` by knowing what are they, it seems to be very difficult for me to understand in what circumstances they proved to be useful.

Can anyone give one or two concrete example of three of them?

Comment: Use `unique_ptr` when only one thing should own the pointer.  Use `std::shared_ptr` if you want multiple things to share ownership. Use `weak_ptr` to hand out a stub that can get you the pointer, if it hasn't already been destroyed.

Comment: All you have to do is imagine a world with **only** raw pointers.  `weak_ptr` helps solve circular reference problem.

Comment: In my opinion, best to use `std::unique_ptr` (along with *non-owning* raw pointers as function parameters), and avoid `std::shared_ptr`.  Sometimes `std::shared_ptr` really is the best solution, and only in those cases would I consider it.  In contrast to C# on the .NET platform, which all objects are much like having `std::shared_ptr` everywhere.  [F.27](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-shared_ptr) for a shared_ptr reason and example.

Comment: Not a complete duplicate because that question is only about shared/weak ones, but there’re many good answers there: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48834271/126995

Comment: Read [_Effective Modern C++_](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/effective-modern-c/9781491908419/), the answer is there.

Comment: One important use case of weak_pte that I came across just recently is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27085782/how-to-break-shared-ptr-cyclic-reference-using-weak-ptr

Answer (score 3):

I assume you know what each of these smart pointers do so I am not going to explain them. Instead I will give you examples of how I have used them in my own code or from libraries I have used that need them.

std::unique_ptr: Can be returned from an API to indicate that the resource needs to be managed by the caller and that it is not safe to share the object. For example, gRPC creates `CompletionQueue` instances like this. `CompletionQueue` has sensitive lifetime and synchronization requirements. By returning `unique_ptr` it is clear that the caller is responsible for lifetime management and it makes it cumbersome to share the `CompletionQueue`. It is still not impossible to share it (can get the raw pointer from the `unique_ptr` or use a reference to the `unique_ptr`, both of which are typically code smells).

std::shared_ptr/std::weak_ptr: Not the simplest use case, but here we go...

```
AudioPlayer::AudioPlayer() {
   thread_local std::weak_ptr<AudioPlayerMixer> mixedOutput;

   if (mixedOutput.expired()) {
      m_mixedOutput = std::make_shared<AudioPlayerMixer>();
      mixedOutput = m_mixedOutput;
   } else {
      m_mixedOutput = mixedOutput.lock();
   }
}
```

In this example, all `AudioPlayer` instances on a thread need to have their audio mixed together using `AudioPlayerMixer`. So, each `AudioPlayer` has a `shared_ptr<AudioPlayerMixer>` so that when the last `AudioPlayer` instance holding the `shared_ptr` is destroyed, the mixer will be as well. The usage of `thread_local` just facilitates having a unique `AudioPlayerMixer` per thread. The `thread_local` storage of the `AudioPlayerMixer` should not prolong the life of the mixer as the lifetime of the `AudioPlayerMixer` is decided by the existence of `AudioPlayer` instances (ie. no `AudioPlayer` => no `AudioPlayerMixer`) - this is why a `weak_ptr` is used. `mixedOutput.expired() == true` means that either no `AudioPlayer` has been created on this thread or all previously existing players were deleted. `mixedOutput.expired() == false` means another `AudioPlayer` exists on this thread and the current `AudioPlayer` needs to get a `shared_ptr` to the same mixer. Note you have to be careful when using `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` from multiple threads as they are not thread safe. In this example, `thread_local` and the fact that `AudioPlayer` is only created and destroyed within the same thread ensures it is safe.

Of course, this could have all be done without the smart pointers but the smart pointers help communicate the intent of the code better.

Comment: If the goal is to get a `shared_ptr` from a `weak_ptr` it is usually safer and better to just use `.lock()` and then to check if the produced `shared_ptr` actually points to something or not, instead of using `expired` first. `lock()` returns a default constructed instance if it is expired.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Good point, thanks for the simplification.