# Actual uses of shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, ownership, reference-counting

For me, `shared_ptr` seems like a lazy solution to memory management, instead of using a well thought zero overhead ownership system of`unique_ptr` for owning pointers, raw pointers for  observing pointers, and `std::move` to pass ownership around.

The only place where I actually need shared ownership is in a multithreaded context, but even in this case I do not use `shared_ptr` as it is not thread-safe.

I have never seen a use for `shared_ptr` other than gaining time in development (which is a valid reason but not when writing performant code) which leads to me believe that `shared_ptr` is entirely useless.

Has anyone seen an actual use of `shared_ptr` where reference counting is really required?

EDIT:
There seems to be many uses in a multithreaded environment. What about in a single-threaded context?

Comment: Well, what does "really required" mean? Are you looking for "True Scotsmen"? Simple use case: Effective way to handle shared ownership in a component architecture, where you don't care who owns an object as long as it is destroyed when nobody holds a reference anymore.

Comment: I'm currently working with objects that are created dynamically by thread A, then passed by shared-pointer-reference from thread A to thread B, and after that both thread A and thread B use them simultaneously for various things (with appropriate serialization, of course) and simply drop the shared-pointers when they are done with them.  Shared pointers make managing the lifetimes of those objects much easier than it would be otherwise.

Comment: By really required I mean when it can’t be solved by unique_ptr and raw pointers, which avoid any overhead. I don’t see why your example can’t be solved by unique_ptr and raw pointers...

Comment: @Jeremy I thought shared_ptr was not thread safe...

Comment: A `unique_ptr` couldn't be held by two threads at the same time.  A raw pointer would be dangerous to delete without risking a use-after-free error by the other thread.

Comment: The reference-count is thread-safe/atomic; the object it references is not (i.e. you have to provide your own serialization for that)

Comment: I use `shared_ptr` in a class that is protected by `scoped_lock(mutex)` in a multi-threaded application.  I like the `reset` and `get` methods of them.  Ex.: `boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket;`

Comment: Multiple views in a GUI when you have no idea which Window the user will close last.

Comment: @Jeremy what about in a single threaded context?

Comment: BTW, if used correctly there is no reason a `std::shared_ptr` should be slower than a raw pointer (because you should only access its object through its raw pointer). An *incorrect* use for `std::shared_ptr` is as a "safe" replacement for raw pointers, which is a no no. The `std::shared_ptr` should simply be there to manage the lifetime of the object - nothing more.

Comment: Any time you're working with a DAC (directed acyclic graph) data structure, shared pointers make things much easier to manage.  (A simple tree only requires a unique_ptr, of course, but when each node can have multiple parent-nodes, then you end up doing reference-counting to know when to delete the node, at which point you might as well let the shared-pointer class handle that for you)

Comment: Very few things are "really required". Do we really require high level languages when we could just write all programs in assembler? - Being able to write clear and maintainable code efficiently is also important.

Comment: @Galik there is a an overhead for destruction/ copying. In my understanding raw pointers should be used as observing pointers, and owning pointers should be unique_ptr...

Comment: This question: [shared_ptr Real life use-cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48834271/shared-ptr-real-life-use-cases/48836802) provides some good examples

Comment: @SomeProgrammer Yes but you should hardly ever copy/destroy them compared to how often you use the object they point to. So for most uses the overhead is negligible.

Answer (score 4):

There are no use cases where `shared_ptr` is “required”, as C++ is Turing-complete without it. As such, any use case of `shared_ptr` is necessarily to improve developer efficiency.

You mention a lack of thread safety, but the reference counting provided by `shared_ptr` is absolutely thread safe. You may have been confusing that with the lack of thread safety of an individual `shared_ptr`. But if two threads have different `shared_ptr`s to the same object, there’s no thread safety concerns around the reference counting.

As such, since you seem to indicate that thread safe reference counting would be a useful thing to have available (not *required*, though!), I think that’s the most slam-dunk use case for you.

Beyond that, I’d point out that there is nothing fundamentally special about multithreading compared to various things you might do in a single threaded context. If you can have two threads which both care - at least temporarily - about an object, and neither one wants to assert full control over its lifetime, then you can have equivalent cases with multiple systems on a single thread.

Comment: I know that c++ is Turing complete without it, but that doesn’t mean shared_ptr or an alternative form of reference counting is not required... In multithreaded contexts, I now understand that there are perfectly valid uses of shared ptr now, but what about in single threaded contexts ?

Comment: @SomeProgrammer Any limited in size object cache.  The cache has shared_ptr(s) to the objects it manages and hands out weak_ptr(s).  The cache manager removes objects from the cache as needed.  Typical use 3D scene resource loader/manager.